# Google CloudPrint Service not working under Win10: Job failed (spool failed) / error 3

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, printing, printer, google-cloud-print

OS: Windows 10 (fresh install)

Printer: HP Laserjet 1320 over USB

Problem:

I cannot print using the google cloudprint service and windows 10.

The printer prints OK locally with local files and prints OK if I use Google Chrome to share the printer to CloudPrint and print via CloudPrint but it fails with the following errors in the log if I use the Google CloudPrint service and try to print via CloudPrint:

```
[3736:3464:0822/145936:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(420)] CP_CONNECTOR: Handling success status update response, printer id: 582918e4-1211-2379-37fc-b3387e45c456
[3736:3464:0822/145936:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(510)] CP_CONNECTOR: Starting printing, printer id: 582918e4-1211-2379-37fc-b3387e45c456
[3736:2312:0822/145936:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(262)] CP_CONNECTOR: Job failed (spool failed)
[3736:3464:0822/145936:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(591)] CP_CONNECTOR: Job failed, printer id: 582918e4-1211-2379-37fc-b3387e45c456, job id: 0c964985-58c7-e29f-6898-4dc6039f35e6, error: 3
[3736:3464:0822/145936:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(540)] CP_CONNECTOR: Updating job status, printer id: 582918e4-1211-2379-37fc-b3387e45c456, job id: 0c964985-58c7-e29f-6898-4dc6039f35e6, job status: 2
```

I need the use of the cloudprint service rather than chrome as the machine is often run heaedless or via RDP and I need CloudPrint printer support from boot.

My complete log can be viewed here:

http://pastebin.com/cn2MJYp5

Any more info required will be gladly provided!!

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this:

It turns out there was a regression in code in Chrome v52 which has now been patched in Chrome v53.

As of time of writing the solution is to move to Chrome Beta for Windows, currently based on Chrome v53 and then re-register the printed via the Cloud Print Service.